# Autocomplete Primefaces not record to database

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm using:

- Primefaces 4.0
- Netbeans 8.0.1
- Omnifaces 2.1
- JSF 2.2
- Hibernate 4.3.1

and I implement a Autocomplete in primefaces, the view shows the list from database, but at the moment to record in the database, the result is that the id is null

here my code:

```
<h:form id="formInsertar">
            <p:messages autoUpdate="true"/>
            <p:panelGrid columns="2">
                <p:outputLabel value="Id:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.id}" disabled="true"/>
                <p:outputLabel value="Nombre:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.nombre}" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Buscar x tipo" for="tipo"/>
                <p:autoComplete id="tipo" value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.tipousuario}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"
                                completeMethod="#{tipoUsuarioBean.completarTipo}" var="t"
                                itemLabel="#{t.nombre}" itemValue="#{t}">

                </p:autoComplete>
                <p:outputLabel value="Login:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.login}" />
                <p:outputLabel value="Clave:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.clave}" />
                <p:outputLabel value="eMail:" />
                <p:inputText value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.email}" />
            </p:panelGrid>
            <p:commandButton value="Crear" update=":formMostrar" actionListener="#{usuarioBean.insertar()}" 
                             />
        </h:form>
```

My Dao:

```
@Override
public List<Tipousuario> buscarxNombre(String nombre) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Tipousuario.class);
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(nombre)){
        criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nombre",nombre.toUpperCase(),MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
    }
    return criteria.list();
}
```

My Bean:

```
public List<Tipousuario> completarTipo(String nombre){
    TipoUsuarioDao tipodao = new TipoUsuarioDaoImp();
    tipousuarios = tipodao.buscarxNombre(nombre);
    return tipousuarios;
}
```

And the error:

> WARN:   SQL Error: 515, SQLState: 23000
>   ERROR:   No se puede insertar el valor NULL en la columna 'tipousuario_id', tabla 'miApp.dbo.usuario'. La columna no admite valores NULL. Error de INSERT.
>   Información:   could not execute statement

Please I need some help. Thanks

PD: Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is an SQL error. Not really related to primefaces.

Comment: "*The column does not allow `NULL` values.*" Attempting to insert a `NULL` value into a column that disallows `NULL` values.

Comment: That is because it is not capturing the id autocomplete, my question was that that is not capturing the id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I solved it.
Next steps:

- The property correct to autocomplete is *ListConverter* not *SelectItemsConverter*
- The way to instead is below:

  ```xhtml
  <p:outputLabel value="Buscar x tipo" for="tipo"/>
      <p:autoComplete id="tipo"
                      value="#{usuarioBean.usuario.tipousuario}" 
                      completeMethod="#{tipoUsuarioBean.completarTipo}" 
                      var="t"
                      itemLabel="#{t.nombre}"
                      itemValue="#{t}"
                      forceSelection="true">

          <o:converter converterId="omnifaces.ListConverter"
                       list="#{tipoUsuarioBean.tipousuarios}"/>

          <p:ajax event="itemSelect" process="@form" />
      </p:autoComplete>
  ```